# MaterialApp.router constructor shows blank screen upon rebuild

Tags: flutter

Whenever the `MaterialApp.router(...)` is rebuilt, through code or even hot-reload, it shows a blank screen only. I use the *auto-route* package to handle navigation, and I followed their [setup steps](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route#installation) and ended up with the following code

```
class MyApp extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    ...
    final _appRouter = AppRouter();
    return MaterialApp.router(
      ...
      routerDelegate: _appRouter.delegate(),
      routeInformationParser: _appRouter.defaultRouteParser(),
      builder: (context, router) => router!,
    );
  }
```

With this code I'm getting the blank screen, but whenever I change to just

```
class MyApp extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    return MaterialApp(
      ...
      home: HomeScreen(),
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

It works fine again. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This happens because you are declaring the AppRouter inside the build function, that creates a completely new router with each build, just remove it and declare it as a widget variable. It would look something like this:

```
class MyApp extends ConsumerWidget {
  final _appRouter = AppRouter();
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    ...
    return MaterialApp.router(
      ...
      routerDelegate: _appRouter.delegate(),
      routeInformationParser: _appRouter.defaultRouteParser(),
      builder: (context, router) => router!,
    );
  }
}
```